# How to get all product using amazon mws ListMatchingProducts api?

Tags: php, amazon-mws

I am trying to get all product that are in my client's seller account. The problem is that Amazon MWS ListMatchingProducts api call returns a response of maximum 10 products.  Actually I want to get all products that are in the seller's account. I have tried hard to find a solution for several days. Any helpful suggestion will be highly appreciated and thanked.

Answer (score 2):

The `ListMatchingProducts` operation is part of the **MWS Products API**, which is meant to access information about products that are in the Amazon catalog, not listings that are in your seller account.

To access the listings in your seller account, you need to use the [MWS Reports API](https://developer.amazonservices.com/api.html?group=bde&section=reports&version=latest). The list of report types related to listings is [here](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/reports/Reports_ReportType.html#ReportTypeCategories__ListingsReports).

Comment: Thanks for the answer Cosmo Harrigan. 
Actually i want to get all products from amazon catalog using ListMatchingProducts operation.
Whenever i submit a request through ListMatchingProducts api.
It only returns 10 results/products.
Please tell me a way to get all products information using ListMatchingProducts operation.
And if i submit a request again it again returns the same 10 results/products again.E.g
If i set query as "books" it returns 10 results.
If another request is submitted the result the same.

Comment: That's different than the question you posted. What is the motivating use case? The ListMatchingProducts operation does not support paging for additional results. You must use a specific enough query, and then utilize the limited result set that is provided.

Comment: I have now used MWS Reports API(GetReport operation).And its returning listings in my seller account.And now problem is that it is returning response in string format.I want to know how to get response in XML format.

Answer (score 2):

Like Cosmo said, the `ListMatchingProducts` operation is used to query products in the Amazon catalog by known product identifiers like UPC, EAN, etc.  and you cannot use it to query products in your own seller account.  Check out the Inventory Report in the [Reports API](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/reports/Reports_ReportType.html).  If you use one of the [client libraries](https://developer.amazonservices.com/gp/mws/api.html/184-8769676-6138501?ie=UTF8&group=bde&section=reports&version=latest), then most of the work is done for you.  Just retrieve the report, then process the xml however you need to to get the data you want out of it.